# Get a delimited string from XML with SQL Server 2005 XQuery

Tags: sql-server-2005, xquery

I cannot seem to get a [comma-]delimited string out of an XML doc using just SQL Server 2005 XQuery.

I have:

```
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_A</Name>
  <Value>Val_A</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_B</Name>
  <Value>Val_B</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_C</Name>
  <Value>Val_C</Value>
</AAA>
... (etc.)
```

... and would like to get `Val_A,Val_B,Val_C...` - a comma-delimited string.

I can convert to a table then back to string with FOR XML, but thought there is a direct way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - this will work for any number of `<AAA>` nodes in an XML variable:

```
DECLARE @Input XML = '<AAA>
  <Name>Name_A</Name>
  <Value>Val_A</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_B</Name>
  <Value>Val_B</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_C</Name>
  <Value>Val_C</Value>
</AAA>'

SELECT
    STUFF(
    (SELECT 
        ',' + AAA.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
     FROM
        @Input.nodes('/AAA') AS Node(AAA)
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
```

Output is:

```
Val_A,Val_B,Val_C
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that adding a string (",") to the XML would work and was using a CTE with the same .nodes() query to then do the FOR XML PATH separately!  
Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml = '
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_A</Name>
  <Value>Val_A</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_B</Name>
  <Value>Val_B</Value>
</AAA>
<AAA>
  <Name>Name_C</Name>
  <Value>Val_C</Value>
</AAA>
'

select @xml.value('(/AAA[1]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(10)')+','+
       @xml.value('(/AAA[2]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(10)')+','+
       @xml.value('(/AAA[3]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string-join(/AAA/Value, ",")
```

(You might need to adapt the beginning of the Path expression depending on how you read your input)