# SQL / Visual studio Search bar display using wildcard

Tags: c#, search, wildcard

I would like a search bar that would look at the input and give all possible solutions rather that only that are matching.

This is for a web-app that displays all item descriptions per SQL db table and matches any or all words . But, I should be able to put in couple of texts and it should display all letters that are matching , Wildcard so to speak

SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')

I expect the output to give results for any text / strings / numbers matching and display all, but it is only giving certain results . 
Is there a wildcard that i can add so all matching can display?

Example :
***Search Bar :*** John good
*Expected O/P:*

John is awesome, good and clever
John is good
John is not good

*Actual O/P:*

Nothing

***Search Bar :*** John is
*Expected O/P:*

John is awesome, good and clever
John is good
John is not good
John is great

*Actual O/P:*
John is awesome, good and clever
John is good
John is not good
John is great

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: I updated the post , hope its clear @Ben

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be done.
lets say that you search for `John good`.

What you will do then is split it as "John", "good", then your search will look like this instead

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([name] LIKE '% John %') or ([name] LIKE '% good %')
```

This will give you the result you are intressted in.

Comment: Thanks Alen,  
  
In other words 

SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([name] LIKE '%' + [at]Name + '%') or ([name] LIKE '%' + [at] Name + '%')

?? 
I want to pass on any number of words and it should produce the results that match those particular strings

Comment: look att how Google do thair search, here is an article that may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816039/how-do-you-use-t-sql-full-text-search-to-get-results-like-google